# How to convert shapefile to KML file using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, kml, convert, layers

Python script that checks to see if a specific layer file exists in the current workspace
and, if it does, converts the layer file to a KML file. Does it work with a shapefile?

Code so far:

```
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("cities.shp"):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(file)
    #print "Name: " + desc.BaseName
    name = desc.baseName

    if name == "cities.shp":
         arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion("cities.shp", "cities.kmz")
         print "Converted"
    else:
        print ("There are no layers in ",env.workspace,".")
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[Layer To KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000)** tool only takes as input:

> The feature or raster **layer** or **layer** file (.lyr) to be converted to
>   KML

Consequently, you will need to use the **[Make Feature Layer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006p000000)** first which

> Creates a feature **layer** from an input feature class [including shapefiles] or **layer** file.